# Uploading to Bigquery with correctly provided timezone in timestamp (prevent auto UTC)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, google-bigquery

How do you add the time zone into a dataframe timestamp that you upload to Bigquery (BQ)?

When uploading a dataframe that includes timestamps to Google BQ you need to specify the UTC offset or the time zone name to make sure you keep the correct timezone. If you don't, BQ will automatically convert your timestamp to UTC.

The timestamp format that BQ can read has the fallowing canonical format: `YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDD]][time zone]`

My question is about setting the `[time zone]` part correctly. According to BQ documentation:

*A string-formatted timestamp may include a time zone. When a time zone is not explicitly specified, the default time zone, UTC, is used. Time zones are represented by strings in one of these two canonical formats:*

- Offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), or the letter Z for UTC
- Time zone name from the tz database

I have a dataframe which includes timestamps that have been converted to a local time zone with the below command:

`df['date'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')`

The outcomes look like this and includes a UTC offset:

`2019-02-15 00:02:26+01:00` and 
`2019-04-01 00:03:40+02:00`*(Daylight saving time)*

However, when uploading this into BQ through the API, the values are converted to UTC. And I receive the following values.

`2019-02-15 00:01:26 UTC` and 
`2019-04-01 00:01:40 UTC`

What could be the case for BigQuery not accepting my Timestamp formatting?

I load the job with these lines of code:

```
dataset_ref = client.dataset('dataset_name')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('table_name')
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_ref, job_config=job_config).result()
```

Comment: Hi WvonR, Can you advise which document you tried and what SQL is not working for you. You can see this answer which describes BigQuery TimeZone support https://stackoverflow.com/a/40140352/1031958, Hope this has all the details to help you for this use case

Comment: Hi @TamirKlein what do you mean with which document? The question is not about SQL but about loading the data. When you load the data I want to specify the timezone already in order to have the table loaded with the correct schema and specifications. That way I don't have to worry about SQL or create a specific view etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: How did you determine that "BQ converts these inputs to UTC"? When you *query* a TIMESTAMP column, the UI will use a default time zone of UTC to display the values. TIMESTAMPs are not *stored* with an associated time zone, however.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I added a screenshot to show you how the inputs end up in UTC format. I am not querying anything but **loading** data. If TIMESTAMP's are not stored with an associated time zone, how do you explain the information on this page: [Bigquery documentation on timezone](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#time-zone-name)

Comment: When you convert a TIMESTAMP, which is an absolute point in time, to other representations, you can optionally provide a time zone. If you don't, BigQuery defaults to using UTC.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I have done this. Through the BQ API i'm uploading the following date (e.g. `2019-05-01 11:57:31+02:00`) which corresponds exactly to the online documentation mentioned above. When querying the same row, this date comes out like this `2019-05-01 09:57:31`. The time has been adjusted and the offset has been stripped. Any Idea what the case for this could be?

Comment: BigQuery does not store the time zone alongside TIMESTAMP values. When you query a TIMESTAMP column, you need to pass a time zone if you want the results to reflect it, e.g. `STRING (timestamp, '+02:00')`

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I get it now. The documentation I'm referring to is only for standardSQL and does not consider the storage types of BQ itself. In order to get what I want I would need to just load the UTC Timestamps and get the timezone adjusted by running the correct query in BQ. I was hoping to have the data loaded in there adjusted already but that is not an option I'm afraid. Thanks for the answer! Put it in if you want so I can mark it!

Comment: Added an answer to that effect to make it easier to find in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery does not store the time zone alongside TIMESTAMP values. When you query a TIMESTAMP column, you need to pass a time zone if you want the results to reflect it, e.g. `STRING (timestamp, '+02:00')`. One option is to store the time zone name (or hour offset from UTC) in a separate column. When you want the query results to use that original time zone, you can use that column, e.g. `STRING(timestamp, time_zone)`.

Comment: Then is it impossible to load timestamp data with timezone? i.e. `2014-09-27 12:30:00+07:00` format works although `America/Los_Angeles` doesn't.