# Google BigQuery: Importing DATETIME fields using Avro format

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

I have a script that downloads data from an Oracle database, and uploads it to Google BigQuery. This is done by writing to an Avro file, which is then uploaded directly using BQ's python framework. The BigQuery tables I'm uploading the data to has predefined schemas, some of which contain DATETIME fields.

[As  BigQuery now has support for Avro Logical fields](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#logical_types), import of timestamp data is no longer a problem. However, I'm still not able to import datetime fields. I tried using string, but then I got the following error:

`Field CHANGED has incompatible types. Configured schema: datetime; Avro file: string.`

I also tried to convert the field data to timestamps on export, but that produced an internal error in BigQuery:

`An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. Error: 3144498`

Is it even possible to import datetime fields using Avro?

Answer (score 0):

In Avro, the logical data types must include the [`attribute logicalType`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Logical+Types), it is possible that this field is not included in your schema definition.

[Here](https://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=3781#gist97315673) there are a couple of examples like the following one. As far as I know the type can be int or long, but logicalType should be date:

```
{
'name': 'DateField', 
'type': 'int',
'logicalType': 'date'
}
```

Once the logical data type is set, try again. The documentation does indicate it should work:

```
Avro logical type --> date  
Converted BigQuery data type --> DATE
```

In case you get an error, it would be helpful to check the schema of your avro file, you can use this command to obtain its details:

`java -jar`[`avro-tools-1.9.2.jar`](http://avro.apache.org/releases.html#Download)`getschema my-avro-file.avro`

**UPDATE**

For cases where DATE alone doesn't work, please consider that the TIMESTAMP can store the date and time with a [number of micro/nano seconds](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Timestamp+%28millisecond+precision%29) from the unix epoch, 1 January 1970 00:00:00.000000 UTC (UTC seems to be the default for avro). Additionally, the values stored in an avro file (of type DATE o TIMESTAMP) are independent of a particular time zone, in this sense, it is very similar to BigQuery [Timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type) data type.

Comment: The problem is that the date logical type does not contain time. Which makes sense, because I should be able to use timestamp. My problem however is that BigQuery timestamps are exclusively UTC, and I'm not interested in translating my timestamp to another timezone.

Comment: You are right, UTC is the default time zone in BigQuery. As this is a separate issue and the original question was addressed (Is it possible to import datetime fields using Avro?), you might want to open a new thread or search for existing recommendations like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57472726/9457843). I personally recommend to include UTC date and time in the avro file so that BQ can store your correct time in UTC. Then, when querying the data, you can use functions like `DATETIME(timestamp_expression [, timezone])` to transform again to the original time zone, or other.

Comment: I see. So I gather the answer to my question is that no, datetime can not be imported using Avro files. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Thank you, just would like to add an update in case helps others.